# Open a new window in JS but the browser is scrolled straight down to the bottom automatically

Tags: javascript, struts2

I was developing a struts web application, in one of my JSP I created a button to open a new window. The way I did it is:

```
window.open(location,'_blank');
```

everything works fine except the new window is always scrolled down to the bottom itself. How to show the top part instead?

I am using Chrome.

Comment: Does the `location` variable have a hash at the end? Such as `http://www.example.com/some/page.html#whatever`?

Comment: var location ="executeTemplateInstantiation.action?shifterString="+shifterString+"&templateLinesIds="+allLinesId+"&lineConcatenation="+lineConcatenation.....    just a action concatenated with some more parameters no #

Answer (score 0):

Include place this JS at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag.

```
<script>window.scrollTo(0,0);</script>
```

Or you could simply use jQuery if your page is already including it:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(window).scrollTop(0);});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open(someUrl, '_blank');
newWindow.onload = function(){
    newWindow.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
newWindow.onload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.open(location,'_blank','top=50');
```